# Как проверять, одинаковы или нет имена псевдонимов типов?

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть простенький код

```
typedef int typeint1;
typedef int typeint2;

std::cout << std::is_same<typeint1, typeint2>::value << std::endl; //true
std::cout << std::is_same<int, typeint2>::value << std::endl;      //true
```

Есть ли стандартная шаблонная магия, чтобы проверять сходтсво/различие на уровне имён псевдонимов? Что-то типа:

```
std::cout << std::is_same_typedef<typeint1, typeint2>::value << std::endl; //false
std::cout << std::is_same_typedef<typeint1, typeint1>::value << std::endl; //true
```

Comment: Может вам нужны ada-style типы? Тогда стоит смотреть в сторону strong typedef.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простое сравнение разных имен реализовать несложно, достаточно сделать stringize:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define IS_SAME_NAME(A_fist_type, A_second_type) \
    (not ::std::strcmp(#A_fist_type, #A_second_type))

int main()
{
    typedef int typeint1;
    typedef int typeint2;

    std::cout << IS_SAME_NAME(typeint1, typeint2) << std::endl; //false
    std::cout << IS_SAME_NAME(typeint1, typeint1) << std::endl; //true

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И как этим воспользоваться в шаблоне, когда тип выводится, а не прописывается в макросе литералом?

Comment: @Harry Очевидно никак, однако пример из вопроса, когда параметры передаются прямо, вполне будет работать.

Comment: Это да, но что-то я не могу представить человека, который такое будет писать... :)

Comment: @Harry Отчего же? Такого рода проверка может пригодится например когда сами имена типов тоже задаются препроцессором.

Answer (score 2):

Вряд ли это возможно, ведь `int`, `typeint1` и `typeint2` означают один и тот же тип.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/397420)

Comment: @zcorvid Как это не является? "Это невозможно" - это тоже ответ.

Comment: словом "невозможно "  нужно воспользоваться очень осторожно, особенно в C++...

Answer (score 0):

Такое не возможно. Дело в том, что псевдоним не является типом сам по себе, он еще одно обозначение для типа. От сюда следует что `std::is_same` (как и ни что другое в плюсах) не различает псевдонимы, а только типы.

Answer (score 0):

Это скорее всего не возможно. Потому что `typedef1` и `typedef2` неявно преобразовываются в `int`. Таков стандарт С++. Но, попробуйте использовать `strong typedef`, у них такой проблемы нету.